# My @property is declared yet I still get may not respond to warning

Tags: iphone, ios, properties

I don't like warnings lying around and this one has been bothering me. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I have tons of properties using this same approach and none of them are giving me warnings. Why doesn't Xcode recognize this one?

While the app works as expected, Xcode gives me the following compile time warning:

```
'OnlinePeerBrowser' may not respond to '-setMyParent:'
```

My property declaration in OnlinePeerBrowser.h

```
#import "WelcomeViewController.h"

@interface OnlinePeerBrowser : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate> {

    WelcomeViewController *_myParent;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) WelcomeViewController *myParent;
```

OnlinePeerBrowser.m has

```
@synthesize myParent=_myParent;
```

I am getting the warning on setMyParent in WelcomeViewController.m here...

```
#import "WelcomeViewController.h"
#import "OnlinePeerBrowser.h"

@implementation WelcomeViewController

- (void)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker didSelectConnectionType:(GKPeerPickerConnectionType)type {
... 

    OnlinePeerBrowser *controller = [[OnlinePeerBrowser alloc] 
                                     initWithNibName:@"OnlinePeerBrowser" bundle:nil];
    [controller setMyParent:self];
}
```

Also, what is weird is that I can not use the dot syntax here either.

```
controller.myParent = self;
```

gives me the following error:

```
/Users/vesselhead/Development/iPhone/DJBox/WelcomeViewController.m:254: error: request for member 'myParent' in something not a structure or union
```

I feel like I must be missing something very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've posted looks correct.  That means that the compiler is pulling in another declaration of the `OnlinePeerBrowser` class from somewhere.

- Check for circular imports.
- Check if you have multiple copies of the OnlinePeerBrowser.h file.
- Add the line `#warning Testing` to your OnlinePeerBrowser.h file.  That warning should then appear in the log when you compile.  If that warning doesn't appear then that file isn't being picked up by the compiler.

If it's a circular import then don't import "WelcomeViewController.h" in "OnlinePeerBrowser.h".  Instead, use a forward declaration in OnlinePeerBrowser.h, e.g. `@class WelcomeViewController` , and import "WelcomeViewController.h" in OnlinePeerBrowser.m

Comment: No dups of OnlinePeerBrowser.h. WelcomeViewController.m includes WelcomeViewController.h & OnlinePeerBrowser.h. OnlinePeerBrowser.h includes WelcomeViewController.h. So it is circular. Now for a really stupid q - How do I see the full build log in Xcode 4.2? I am showing the warning in the Issues Navigator; however, this is an interpreter right?

Comment: Darren, you lead me to the answer... I had import instead of include. Doh! Switching to include makes Xcode deal with the cyclical dependencies. That was one thing in C++ that drove me batty #ifdef. Can you update your answer and I will check it.

Comment: The build log is available in the Log Navigator (Command+7).  I've updated my answer for your circular import problem.

Comment: You want to use #import, not #include.  With #import you don't have to worry about protecting headers with #ifdef, but neither deal with circular dependancies.  For that you need to use forward class declarations.

Comment: So basically you are saying I am cheating if I use #include and leave it up to Xcode to deal with the cyclical dependencies. The right thing to do is use @class WelcomeViewController. Thank you for making me a better programmer ;)-

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Circular Imports create an issue with the compiler.
Instead of using

```
#import "WelcomeViewController.h"
```

in OnlinePeerBrowser.h move that line to the OnlinePeerBrowser.m and add

```
@class WelcomeViewController
```

to the OnlinePeerBrowser.h

this will allow you to set the Class of myParent and _myParent to WelcomeViewController and not have the Circular Import.

**Alternatively**:

you may want to use a @protocol that the WeclomeViewController would have to adhere to. Then you would only have to import the Classes in one direction.

the implementation for a Protocol property would be as Follows

```
//#import "WelcomeViewController.h"

@protocol OnlinePeerBrowserParent <NSObject>
@required
- (NSString*) informationFromParent;
@end


@interface OnlinePeerBrowser : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate> {

    id<OnlinePeerBrowserParent> _myParent;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<OnlinePeerBrowserParent> myParent;
```

notice the Protocol is on the OnlinePeerBrowser.h so you can import the OnlinePeerBrowser.h and get the Protocol by default.

finally you implement the Protocol in the WelcomeViewController as so

```
@implementation WelcomeViewController<OnlinePeerBrowserParent>

- (NSString*) informationFromParent
{
    return @"My Parental Info";
}

...... etc
```

Comment: Thanks Volure DarkAngel @Darren already answered the root question for me. But I agree with you that there are times when the protocol is the best choice. I will up arrow for you on that. I didn't want to go to this extent just to get the parent. The modal view should normally have parent but I found a bug I think http://bit.ly/obMWSX

Comment: No problem. I can respect that :) I think he answered it while I was creating this post, so while mine has more information and other details he did give some good debug tips, and answered your question with a concise solution :) Thanks for the vote.